# Is there a standard connection dialog for mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have written an windows form app in C# that gets distributed to various data partners. The purpose of this app is to connect to one of their locally controlled databases, extract data according to SQL they provide and then to send it directly to our services using protected and encrypted methods.

One of the steps each partner needs to perform to pull and send us their data is to connect to their database. Most of my data partners us SQL Server. When these partners select the option to 'Connect to DB' my code executes:

var dialog = new DataConnectionDialog();

dialog.DataSources.Add(DataSource.SqlDataSource);

This presents them with the standard SQL Server connection. We do this because none of the data partners want us to store any part of their connection parameters so we have to ask them each time for all of the details.

I do have at least one data partner who is using MySQL. I had tried to use an ODBC connection datasource but have run into problems. One option to avoid these problems is to use the MySQL.Data library.

However I cannot find a way to bring up the standard MySQL connection dialog so the user can provide servername, port, username, password, etc.

Is there one and if so, how can I call it and obtain the connection parameters?

Thank you,

Comment: There is no built-in connection dialog in Winforms or WPF that you could use. If you really want to use a already existing one you could go and see if you can find any library

Comment: I should have mentioned that I was looking for one as part of a MySQL library. Is there a way to bring up their standard login dialog?

Comment: I think you need more than a dialog hack.  MySQL wont connect to SQL Server to start with so there is that.  I'd explore something like a service or a process to extract the data on "the partners" side so no credentials need leave the premises.  Then fetch the data from a SQLite or CSV file....something like that.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear but I do not need MySQL to connect to SQL Server. Each of my data partners uses my application to connect to their database and then sends the data to my web service. Most of these companies use SQL Server but I do have one that uses MySQL. So my app needs to connect to EITHER SQL Server or MySQL, depending on the partner, but never both at the same time.

Comment: "I cannot find a way to bring up the standard MySQL connection dialog so the user can provide servername, port, username, password,"...so write your own form then. It's only 4 fields.